# Creating a link in a cell in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL as below

```
Col_1   Values
CatA    XCY
CatB    XCY
CatA    XC
CatB    XC
CatA    KJ
CatA    KG
CatA    KFD
CatB    KG
```

There are 2 categories namely CatA and CatB with values. I have  to generat a table1 to tell what is the distinct count of Values

Table 1

```
Col1    Count_of_A  Col2   Count_of_B   Result
CatA       5        CatB      3         Different
```

The result column above is different since the count of values are not matching (5 and 3). Well this is fine

Now the challenge is can we create a link on "Different" cell that shows what are the missing values in CatB
In this example,  2 values are not in CatB and hence when the user clicks on "Different" cell, it should be point to another table or XML format to show the missing values. Is this possible to achieve?

Table 2

```
Values_not_in_CatB
KFD
KJ
```

below is the sql code for that

```
create table sample1 (
    Col1 nvarchar(max),
    [Values] nvarchar(max),
)

insert into sample1
values ('CatA','XCY'), ('CatB','XCY'), ('CatA','XC'), ('CatB','XC'), ('CatA','KJ'), ('CatA','KG'),('CatA','KFD'), ('CatB','KG')

select Col1, count(distinct [Values]) as Counts
from sample1 
group by Col1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hard to know, its not really clear what you are asking. But one thing if for sure SQL Server is not the place to do it. Some form of client application (or report engine) is where you should do this. Note databases don't have cells, they have rows and columns. Cells are a spreadsheet thing.

Comment: @Community i have added the sql code in my question :) please help

Comment: I'm not sure how one would create links in sql server to click on, but perhaps it's enough just to generate two columns which contain the missing values? This is possible, although not really something one should be doing on the server

Comment: then what can be other approaches for this?:) Any idea?

Comment: Usually for links you create some kind of application which calls sql server and fetches data and then displays it. A lot of people write applications in C#, Java or some other language

Comment: Please explain why you are trying to do this on SQL server?

Comment: And why XML format? Why not plain text? You need to explain the bigger picture

Comment: dear all. We do not have any front end application client application like shiny or flask. We only have DB. With this we need to achieve the best way to showcase the data. So only.

Comment: A database engine is just that, a database engine; it hosts data. What you describe is application logic, not data. That you don't have an application just means you need to build one, if this is your requirement.

Comment: SSRS is still free I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say what you are trying to do is not clear, I can give you some code to start with at least you can see where the value match or not:
Than you can use this as data set into an SSRS report if you need to give visibility to end users:

```
WITH CT1DataSet(Cat, Result) AS(
    Select Col1, [Values]
    FROM #sample1
    Where Col1 = 'CatA'
), CT2DataSet(Cat, Result) AS(
    Select Col1, [Values]
    FROM #sample1
    Where Col1='CatB'
), CTALLDataSet(Cat1,Cat2,Result) AS (
    Select ct1.Cat,ct2.Cat,COALESCE(ct1.Result,ct2.Result)
    From CT1DataSet as ct1 
    FULL JOIN CT2DataSet as ct2 ON ct1.Result=ct2.Result  
)

Select *
from CTALLDataSet
```

This code will return a table like this, so you can than do the groping to see if they match or not.

```
Cat1    Cat2    Result
CatA    CatB    XCY
CatA    CatB    XC
CatA    NULL    KJ
CatA    CatB    KG
CatA    NULL    KFD
NULL    CatB    KGL
```